# Idempotence of getGenericType()

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I am trying to define handlers for generic types in a serialization component.

In plain java, I write

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<String> myField;
}

Type type = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myField").getGenericType();
Type typeAgain = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myField").getGenericType();
```

And I can assert that

```
type.equals(typeAgain) == true
type.hashCode() == typeAgain.hashCode()
```

Meaning I can use it in an `HashMap<Type, TypeHandler>`.

However, on android, the same operation with the same class yields both assertions to be false.

2 successive calls to `getGenericType()` on the same field (I have verified that the field itself is identical) don't give the same result.

Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: Just looking at the javadoc, it doesn't seem to have to be the same object. The implementation is JDK/JRE specific.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Apparently no. But the method looks a lot like a getter, so one could expect it to return a private member of some sort.

Comment: I am currently using the String representation of the field, which works, although I don't like it very much.